# how to make a multiple selection field?

Tags: python, django

please help to solve the problem. I have a set of objects:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, 
        verbose_name=u"Пользователь", 
        blank=True, 
        null=True,
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=u"Название", 
        max_length=100,
    )
    video_url = models.URLField(
        verbose_name=u"Адрес видео", 
        max_length=100,
        null=True,
        blank=False,
    )   
    description = HTMLField(
        verbose_name=u'Описание',
        max_length=50000, 
        default=None,
        blank=True,
    )
    views = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name=u'Количество просмотров',
        default=0,
        null=False,
        blank=True,
    )   
    likes = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name=u'Количество лайков',
        default=0,
        null=False,
        blank=True,
    )           
    date = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name=u'Дата создания',
        default=datetime.now(),
        #auto_now=True,
    )
    last_edit_date = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name=u'Дата последнего редактирования',
        default=datetime.now(),
        auto_now=True,
    )       
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name=u'Активно',
        default=True,
    )                   
    is_delete = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name=u'Удалено админом',
        default=False,
    )   
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag.title)
```

I would like to associate each object with multiple tags. for this model is written for the tags:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=u"Название", 
        max_length=100,
    )
    description = HTMLField(
        verbose_name=u'Описание',
        max_length=50000, 
        default=None,
        blank=True,
    )           
    date = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name=u'Дата создания',
        default=datetime.now(),
    )
    last_edit_date = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name=u'Дата последнего редактирования',
        default=datetime.now(),
        auto_now=True,
    )       
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name=u'Активно',
        default=True,
    )                   

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u"""тег"""
        verbose_name_plural = u"""теги"""
```

the problem is that the console displays the following message on any typing errors:

```
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/kinopom_project/kinopom_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/kinopom_project/kinopom_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/kinopom_project/kinopom_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/kinopom_project/kinopom/kinopom/models.py", line 41, in <module>
    class Entry(models.Model):
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/kinopom_project/kinopom/kinopom/models.py", line 94, in Entry
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag.title)        
AttributeError: type object 'Tag' has no attribute 'title'
```

please help fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.title` in the line `tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag.title)`.
ManyToManyField just want a model and you're giving it an attribute of this model which is not working either because Tag is a class not an instance.
If you want your Tag to display it's title when displaying it, just write the **unicode** method.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    #your fields here

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{0}".format(self.title)
```